# How to Clear screen in C programming I'm U using dev c but everything I try seems to failed I have included many different libraries

Tags: c

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(){
//welcome Heading
printf("\t\t\t``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````\n");
printf("\t\t\t\tWelcome to The Bank Management System\n\n");
printf("\t\t\t``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````\n\n");
//password input and validation
char pass[10],password[10]="pass";
int i;
printf("Please Enter Password....");
fflush(stdin);
gets(pass);
    if (strcmp(pass,password)==0){
        printf("WELCOME \nLoading");
        for(i=0;i<5;i++){
            printf(".");
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("incorrect password");
        getche();
        system("tput clear");
        system("cls");
        system("clear");
        main();
    }
return 0;
}
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

> How to Clear screen in C programming I'm U using dev c but everything I try seems to failed I have included many different libraries but none seems to be working.

Comment: There is no screen in C.

Comment: [Never use `gets()`!!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/10077)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you clear the console screen in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347770/how-do-you-clear-the-console-screen-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using *conio.h*. I suggest reading its documentation. It might be downloadable from Microsoft [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979), if you don't find it elsewhere.

For clearing the screen, it has `clrscr()` function. Use that to clear the screen.

---

Note that there are quite a lot of other things wrong with your code, including:

- Don't ever use `gets()`, use eg. `fgets`.
- Don't call `main()` recursively, use a loop.
- Don't use *conio.h*, use *curses* library or direct Windows Win32 API calls if *stdio.h* isn't enough.
- Avoid using `system()` for much of anything.
- Always check for errors when you read user input (or files).

But don't stress about it until later...

Comment: [That might not work, either](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45806357/10077).

Comment: @FredLarson Hopefully the asker can tell of it works for them.

Comment: yes It worked bless